# How to do the SET-UP for the XRP RIPPLED node in Exchange linux

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, jax-rpc, xrp

What How to SETUP XRP RIPPLED in Linux.I am new to this please help me from scratch.with referral link

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your computer meets the minimum [system requirements](https://xrpl.org/system-requirements.html).

You can get direct build by installation, you can refer this [link](https://xrpl.org/install-rippled-on-ubuntu.html).

1. Update repositories:

   `$ sudo apt -y update`
2. Install utilities:

   `$ sudo apt -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget gnupg`
3. Add Ripple's package-signing GPG key to your list of trusted keys:

   ```
   $ wget -q -O - "https://repos.ripple.com/repos/api/gpg/key/public" | \
     sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. Fetch the Ripple repository.

   `$ sudo apt -y update`
5. Install the rippled software package:

   `$ sudo apt -y install rippled`
6. Check the status of the rippled service:

   `$ systemctl status rippled.service`
7. The rippled service should start automatically. If not, you can start it manually:

   `$ sudo systemctl start rippled.service`
8. To configure it to start automatically on boot:

   `$ sudo systemctl enable rippled.service`

Or You can make your own `rippled` build for linux, for that you can use this [link](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/Builds/linux/README.md).

> **Note:** Make sure that first you have to install `boost` having version
>   `1.70.0`, otherwise you may not able to build it. (for manual build only)

Comment: Oh cool,  thanks @Monarth for compiled cocise steps in setting up the ripple service. I am now all setup with the testnet.  However, I am also looking to setup wallets, accounts on ripple and test the transfers, balance checks etc.   Is there any link you can point me to as the documentation / information is spread out.  Or if you can share similar summary of steps, that would be really helpful for me and others that are new to ripple